# How to retrieve data from firebase angularfire2 such that it don't show duplicates

Tags: database, firebase, nosql, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

If I've several documents in collection having key value of "model":"iphone 6" repeated n times and "model":"iphone 7" repeated n times but i want to retrieve each ones. Like it end up showing only iphone 6 and iphone 7 only.

Answer (score 0):

There are two common options:

1. Read the documents in order of their model, and then only show one-document-per-model.

   ```
   var lastModel
   querySnapshot.forEach((phone) => {
     if (phone.data().model <> lastModel) {
       ... 
       lastModel = phone.data().model;
     }
   })
   ```
2. Create a separate collection of models, and show that instead of the documents you currently show.

Option 1 is akin to a `group by` clause in SQL, while option 2 is using a better normalized data model to accomplish the same.

Comment: Hi Frank, really appreciate your help. I'm modeling data which should work like buybackboss.com site. On clicking sell iphone it shows models then on clicking one model it shows further options and then finally it shows price. What you think will be right way to do it.

Comment: In the Firebase Realtime Database I typically model my data to match what is shown on the screen. So I'd have a list of models, and then separate lists of phones for each model. It might be different on Cloud Firestore, but my initial take would be similar.

Comment: Actually I've to show price on basis of model, provider, size and condition selected by user whereas each model has different providers, sizes and conditions are shown same for all models.

Comment: That's just more on the same structure: consider making collections for each of these. Or a single collection of `searchable_categories` where you prefix each document name with the category: `model_dashjdjf`, `model_uewtuwq`, `provider_327ydas`, `provider_ad8ash`, etc.